# JavaScript String

Tags: javascript

Para este ejercicio me solicitaron primero realizar unos pasos que eran:
Implementar un objeto que modele un contador. Un contador se puede incrementar o decrementar, recordando el valor actual. Al resetear un contador, se pone en cero. Además es posible indicar directamente cual es el valor actual. Este objeto debe entender los siguientes mensajes: 6.1 reset() 6.2 inc() 6.3 dec() 6.4 valorActual() 6.5 valorActual(nuevoValor) P.ej. si se evalúa la siguiente secuencia contador.valorActual(10) contador.inc() contador.inc() contador.dec() contador.inc() contador.valorActual() el resultado debe ser 12.

y el código lo tengo de la siguiente forma
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y a partir de este tengo que agregar un string a un contador, donde me pide lo siguiente:
Agregar al contador del ejercicio 6, la capacidad de recordar un String que representa el último comando que se le dio. Los Strings posibles son "reset", "incremento", "decremento" o "actualización" (para el caso de que se invoque valor Actual con un parámetro). Para saber el último comando, se le envía al contador el mensaje ultimo Comando ().

No sé como podría hacer para representar el ultimo comando con un string

Comment: ¿Y la pregunta es..?

Comment: Te sugiero que edites tu pregunta y leas :  [ask] para que te podamos ayudar y evites votos negativos.

Answer (score 1):

La pregunta no es clara, pero considerando el requerimiento que te piden, aquí una solución implementandola en objetos:

Lo primero es definir el objeto con las funciones de incremento, decremento, valor actual y resetear. Después una función en este caso de ejercicio6() que seria el punto de entrada.

```js
function Contador() {
    this.reset = function () {
        this.numero = 0;
    }
    this.inc = function () {
        this.numero += 1;
    }
    this.dec = function () {
        this.numero -= 1;
    }
    this.valorActual = function (valor) {
        if(valor != null) {
            this.numero = valor;
        } else {
            return this.numero;
        }
    }
}


function ejercicio6() {
    let contador = new Contador();
    contador.reset();
    contador.valorActual(10);
    contador.inc();
    contador.inc();
    contador.dec();
    contador.inc();
    console.log(contador.valorActual());
}

ejercicio6();
```